# How to control whitespace of PHP's print_r() method

Tags: php, whitespace

My copy of PHP indents by four spaces when I use the `print_r($array);` method. How do I change this setting to use X number of spaces (or tabs)? Offhand I see nothing relevant listed for the [php.ini](http://php.net/ini.list) file.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, but why would you want to?

Comment: Why would I not? You two have your own preferences and I have mine. Maybe my horizontal screen resolution is 120px, 1,200px or 12,000px. Being able to adjust the whitespace output would allow me to process output data during tests quicker.

Comment: Hi @John, I know it's a long time but i see in your comments you wrote this `echo '<pre>';print_r($array);echo '</pre>';`. But you can write it like so `echo '<pre>'.print_r($array, TRUE).'</pre>';`. Rather than using 2 echo's you can just use one.

Comment: @MohammedAlhanafi Yes, I've been using the second parameter for some time now, a simple `1` counts as `true` too. ☺

Answer (score 3):

How about saving it to a var, and than performing modifications (in a function) to it? print_r does not have special settings to modify the output according to the documentation.

```
$var = print_r($your_array, true);
$var = str_ireplace('    ',' ',trim($var));
var_dump($var);
```

Comment: Interesting...also you *kinda* missed a part however I saw your *intended* path. Since I did not clarify what the four spaces should be replaced with I took four and replaced it with one for your example. If I have to do in-depth debugging I always do something such as `echo '<pre>';print_r($array);echo '</pre>';`. I suppose if this was more than an irritation I could stick this in a function.

Comment: Why do you do that anyway? Just log it to the browser console by printing it in a javascript and the console.log function. You browser will style it in the console and your webpage is not affected. Using print_r for anything else than debugging is just very bad.

Comment: Wait, what about JavaScript? I'm just interested in changing the amount of whitespace PHP outputs, not styling the code with CSS.

Comment: Changing the output of print_r() alone is weird since the function is just designed to give you an overview of your data (no offence). :) Stripping spaces, styling it with CSS or other modifications are not very logic.

Comment: This modifies the values in the output as well as the indentation

Answer (score 1):

Since the documentation doesn't specify this, I've searched the PHP source code to see what `print_r` does and where it gets its indent value.

The 4 spaces are hardcoded into the source. The C-function behind `print_r()` passes through several other functions before it gets to [the one](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend.c#L234) that actually generates the output you get, and this function uses the [`PRINT_ZVAL_INDENT` constant](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend.c#L64) to determine how many spaces each indent gets.

The function retrieves the constant directly, there is no logic around it to see if there's a config value or environment variable that overrides it. So if you want to modify this value to have `print_r()` indent by a different number of spaces you'll have to check out the source code, change the constant to something other than `4` and compile PHP from source.

Comment: "[..] and compile PHP from source." - I like your style for solving this problem. :D

Answer (score 1):

```
function print_rt($obj, $spaces="  ", $return=false) {
    /* © 2022 Peter Kionga-Kamau. Free for unrestricted use.
       Notes: - Not concerned about performance here since print_r is a debugging tool 
              - Single preg_replace() will substitute spaces in contents, hence the loop.
    */ 
    $out = explode("\n",print_r($obj,1));
    foreach ($out as $k=>$v) $out[$k] = preg_replace("/(( ){4})/", $spaces, substr($v,0,strlen($v)-strlen(ltrim($v)))).ltrim($v);
    if($return) return implode("\n",$out); echo implode("\n",$out);
}
```

Usage:

```
print_rt($obj);
```

Comment: A `preg_replace_callback` matching the leading space of each line, with a simple `str_replace('    ', '  ', $matches[1])` inside, would accomplish this without the `strlen` calculations or the explode/loop/implode routine. Any special license needed if `impolode` is changed to `implode` in your code?

Comment: Thanks Markus, no license needed for anything ;-) - also, corrected.

Comment: Wow this was an old question though this still looks good and likely close along the lines of what I would do. ︀

Answer (score 0):

Actually indents are given by "pre" tag of html @see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp)
To actually edit indent use css as

```
pre {
    display: block;
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
    margin: 1em 0;
}
```

and edit the properity of white-spacing.

Comment: using print_r is ugly horizontal code and browsers see "pre" tag and indent it

Comment: Not really relevant to the question directly though I have used `echo '<pre>';print_r($array);echo '</pre>';` for years when debugging so you're following along to some extent.